# the property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested

Tags: 2010, javascript, ribbon

The below question was based on this article:
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/09/10/get-all-folders-using-ecmascriptjavascript-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/

I think the author there didnt post all code, because a simple copy and paste Just does not work.

The following code is supposed to query for the folders list in a specific site pages library.
I think the problem is in the success method, also I have no idea how to debug .js files in sharepoint? any clue?

But its showing this exception on Internet Explorer status bar:
Webpage error details

**Update1**
I tried this line

```
context.Load(allItems,'Include(Title, Id)');
```

But it throws this exception

**Object doesn't support this property or method**

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 5 Mar 2012 14:41:29 UTC

```
Message: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
Line: 5
Char: 62099
Code: 0









 Type.registerNamespace('COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent');

COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent = function () {
    COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initializeBase(this);
}

// the initialize function needs to be called by some script added to the page elsewhere - in the end, it does the important work 
// of calling PageManager.addPageComponent()..
COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initialize = function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function.createDelegate(null, COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initializePageComponent), 'SP.Ribbon.js');
}
COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initializePageComponent = function () {

    var ribbonPageManager = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
    if (null !== ribbonPageManager) {
        ribbonPageManager.addPageComponent(COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.instance);
    }
}

COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.prototype = {
    init: function () { },

    getFocusedCommands: function () {
        return ['COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.GroupCommand', 'COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.TabCommand', 'COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.ContextualGroupCommand', 'COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.RibbonCommand'];
    },

    getGlobalCommands: function () {
        return ['COB.PageComponent.Command.DoAction', 'COB.PageComponent.Command.PopulateDropDown', 'COB.PageComponent.Command.QueryDoAction'];
    },

    canHandleCommand: function (commandId) {
        if ((commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.DoAction') ||
            (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.PopulateDropDown') || (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.QueryDoAction')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    },

    handleCommand: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {
        if (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.GroupCommand') {
            alert("COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.GroupCommand fired");
        }
        if (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.TabCommand') {
            alert("COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.TabCommand fired");
        }
        if (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.ContextualGroupCommand') {
            alert("COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.ContextualGroupCommand fired");
        }
        if (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.RibbonCommand') {
            alert("COB.PageComponent.Command.FieldControl.RibbonCommand fired");
        }
        if (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.QueryDoAction') {
            // this command executes as soon as tab is requested, so do initialization here ready for if our dropdown gets requested..
            //loadCurrentWebLists();
            GetFolders();
        }
        if (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.PopulateDropDown') {
            // actually build the dropdown contents by setting the PopulationXML property to a value with the expected format. We have to deal with possible 
            // timing issues/dependency on core SharePoint JS code with an ExecuteOrDelay..
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function.createDelegate(null, getDropdownItemsXml), 'SP.js');

            properties.PopulationXML = getDropdownItemsXml();
        }
        if (commandId === 'COB.PageComponent.Command.DoAction') {
            // here we're using the SourceControlId to detect the selected item, but more normally each item would have a unique commandId (rather than 'DoAction'). 
            // However this isn't possible in this case since each item is a list in the current web, and this can change..
            var selectedItem = properties.SourceControlId.toString();
            var listName = selectedItem.substring(selectedItem.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            alert("You selected the list: " + listName);
        }
    },

    isFocusable: function () {
        return true;
    },

    receiveFocus: function () {
        return true;
    },

    yieldFocus: function () {
        return true;
    }
}

// **** BEGIN: helper code specific to this sample ****

// some global variables which we'll use with the async processing..
// var lists = null;
var querySucceeded = false;

// use the Client Object Model to fetch the lists in the current site..        
function loadCurrentWebLists() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    this.lists = web.get_lists();

    clientContext.load(lists);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

var allItems;

function GetFolders() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Site Pages');
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllFoldersQuery();
    allItems = list.getItems(query);
    //context.load(allItems);
    //context.Load(allItems, 'Include(Id, DisplayName)');
    context.load(allItems, 'Include(Id, DisplayName)');

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

function success() {
    var FolderNames = "";
    var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
    while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        context.load(currentItem);
        var _contentType = currentItem.get_fileSystemObjectType();
        if (currentItem.get_fileSystemObjectType() == '1') {
            FolderNames += currentItem.get_displayName() + '\n';
        }
    }
    alert(FolderNames);
}


function failed(sender, args) {
    alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    querySucceeded = true;
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    querySucceeded = false;
}

function getDropdownItemsXml() {
    var sb = new Sys.StringBuilder();
    sb.append('<Menu Id=\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.WithPageComponent.PCNotificationGroup.Dropdown.Menu\'>');
    sb.append('<MenuSection DisplayMode=\'Menu\' Id=\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.WithPageComponent.PCNotificationGroup.Dropdown.Menu.Manage\'>');
    sb.append('<Controls Id=\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.WithPageComponent.PCNotificationGroup.Dropdown.Menu.Manage.Controls\'>');
    if (querySucceeded) {
        var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();

        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();

            sb.append('<Button');
            sb.append(' Id=\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.WithPageComponent.PCNotificationGroup.Dropdown.Menu.Manage.');
            sb.append(oList.get_title());
            sb.append('\'');
            sb.append(' Command=\'');
            sb.append('COB.PageComponent.Command.DoAction');
            sb.append('\'');
            sb.append(' LabelText=\'');
            sb.append(SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.htmlEncode(oList.get_title()));
            sb.append('\'');
            sb.append('/>');
        }
    }
    sb.append('</Controls>');
    sb.append('</MenuSection>');
    sb.append('</Menu>');
    return sb.toString();
}

// **** END: helper code specific to this sample ****

COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.registerClass('COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent', CUI.Page.PageComponent);
COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.instance = new COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent();
```

Comment: I tested your code. It works fine for me. So it must be something else.

Comment: I updated the question with all code of the .JS, any idea what should I look for?, when I use the method loadCurrentWebLists it WORKs

Comment: The 'Object doesn't support this property or method' is VERY generic - it means that youre trying to call a method or property that doesn't defined. It will be much easier to help if you debug your code in IE Developer toolbar for example and tell us what's the method/property that's undefined.

Comment: And I still strongly insist that a page component is unnecessary complex for your task - the simple command handler with the function call is enough.

Comment: can you please provide an example? do you mean put the js code in the elements.xml file embedded? Why? Actually I like to separate the files, I think maintenance is easier/!

Comment: I mean that you need a couple of js functio9ns instead a full page component. Of course you can place them in the separate JS file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to get some property that you didn't request explicitly. Maybe it's the Title field you're trying to use. Look at the example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539350.aspx):

```
       function retrieveListItems() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/MySiteCollection');
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My List');

        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Leq>' + 
            '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>100</Value>' + 
            '</Leq></Where></Query><RowLimit>50</RowLimit></View>');

        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, DisplayName)');

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

    }

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

        var listItemInfo = '';

        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();



    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nDisplay name: ' + oListItem.get_displayName();
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

It's the way to tell client object model what fields do you want. The interesting part of this example is:

```
clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, DisplayName)');
```

Comment: that syntax is .net, not javascript, searching I tried this   context.Load(allItems,'Include(Title, Id)');
but now it says  Object doesn't support this property or method @Alex Boev

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that I get the wrong example from that page. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Please see the updated question, I tried to do the same, but I still get the exception. I just cant find any difference.

Comment: I have updated ALL the code of the .JS file.

Answer (score 1):

try with get_id() instead of get_item('Id');

```
var oItem ='';
function retrieveWebSite() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);

        var lstObject = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('Listname');
        oItem = lstObject.getItemById(5);
        clientContext.load(oItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)       
        );
    });
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var look  = oItem.get_item('LookupColumnName').get_lookupValue();
    var title = oItem.get_item('Title');
    var id = oItem.get_id();
    alert("Loook up column value: "+look);
    alert("Title column: "+title);
    alert("Id column value: "+id);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```