# CSOM "invalid request" when including fields

Tags: csom

When calling more than one field the query fails. No descriptive reason why.

[Shorthand as typing on phone]

Working code:

```
 Function getData(){
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
    u = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
    //ctx.load(u,"Email");
    ctx.load(u,"LoginName");
    ctx.loadQueryAsync(Disp,onFail)
 }
 Function Disp(){
     //console.log(u.get_email());
     console.log(u.get_loginName());
 }
 ...fail function, etc..
```

I can choose to have email or loginName output successfully however ctx.loadQueryAsync fails if I try both. Each of the following has been tested in place of previously used load:

```
 ctx.load(u,"Include(Email,LoginName)");
 ctx.load(u,"Include(Email)");
 ctx.loadQuery(u,"Include(Email)");
```

Using any of the above result in a failed query. Message is `Invalid Request` a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidQueryException`. Other error values are undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
function getData(){
ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
this.u = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
ctx.load(u);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Disp,onFail);
```

}

```
 function Disp(){
 console.log(u.get_loginName());
 console.log(u.get_email());
 console.log(u.get_title());
```

}
 ...fail function, etc..

Comment: I receive error that the field has not been loaded. For now ive changed my code to run for one field at a time one after another

Comment: try using this.u = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();

Comment: I have tested and updated with working code.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I won't forget `this` again

Answer (score 0):

Recently had to play with SharePoint JS and here is what I found (tested in SharePoint 2010), see code and comments, code is based on answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863056/the-property-or-field-id-has-not-been-initialized-it-has-not-been-requested):

```
function getListInfo() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    var list = lists.getByTitle('Test');

    context.load(list); // load all fields, seems slow
    //context.load(list, 'Id'); // load only 'Id'
    //context.load(list, 'Title'); // load only 'Title'
    //context.load(list, 'Id', 'Title'); // load only 'Id' and 'Title'
    //context.load(list, 'Include(Id, Title)'); // fails with 'Invalid request' message
    //context.load(list, 'Id', 'Title', 'Description'); // define each field to load as additional parameter
    //context.load(list, ['Id', 'Title', 'Description']); // dynamically define array with fields to load
    //var fields = ['Id', 'Title', 'Description'];
    //context.load(list, fields); // load fields defined in array variable

    context.executeQueryAsync(  //submit query to the server
        function () { //process result in success callback
            console.log('ID:' + list.get_id());
            console.log('Title:' + list.get_title()); 
            console.log('Description:' + list.get_description());
        }, 
        function (sender, args) { //handle error in error callback
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
```

Alternatively you can try to use CAML query (see example [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30828/the-property-or-field-has-not-been-initialized-it-has-not-been-requested-or-the)), in this case Include() works.